# How to check whether the process was restarted by supervisor?

Tags: erlang

To be more precise:

I have a supervisor for dynamic number of children. I want it to use different init function when given child is added and started for the fist time than for all the restarts than will happen later. Optionally, I could use the same function, if it is possible for the process to discover that it was restarted.

Comment: It seems there is no way to get info about process restarts: process state is local (you can not use it to store restarts count), and supervisor module does not provide such functionality. But you can use separate process/ets-table/file to store required information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, **there are side effects** that could be used to find out whether a process was restarted by its supervisor or if it was the first start. For example, you could check the pid of the process and compare it with the pid of the supervisor. However, this is ugly, error prone, and **incoherent with OTP principles**. Indeed, the supervisor itself might have been restarted, or the application or the node itself. It's futile to try to find out.

Instead, following OTP principles, you must make sure that **supervised processes perform the same task whether they were started for the first time or restarted**. This can be achieve with a proper supervision tree that handles dependencies between processes.

The typical reason for desiring to find out if a process was started or restarted is because when they are first started, they must do something which doesn't need to be redone on restart. Eventually, **you need to make sure that what needs to be done on start is undone on termination**, so your processes could do the same thing on start in all situations.

For example, what is to be done could be to start another process (let's call it B), then just link the child and process B on start, then shall the child terminate, B will terminate as well (and reciprocally). You will have to configure the supervisor of B processes to not restart its children (i.e. make them temporary).

**(update based on first comment below)**

Adding factories **only pushes the problem further** but does not solve it entirely. Let's say that you have a factory that is responsible for creating the children. This process could save the states of children and restore them on restart. To achieve this, you would:

- make sure the supervisor does not restart children (they should be specified as temporary);
- create a monitor after the child is created with [`erlang:monitor/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2). Whenever a child terminates, the factory will receive a message. It can then restart the child and provide it with the state;
- get the children to periodically send required information to the factory.

Please note that for memory efficiency that you should restore the state of the process from the factory in a separate message. Indeed, if you put the saved state in the specification, the supervisor will maintain a copy.

You also probably want to make sure that children die if the factory dies. To achieve this, you should [**link**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#link-1) the two processes. As a result, instead of using [`erlang:monitor/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2), you could configure your factory to receive EXIT messages by configuring the process to trap exit (with [`erlang:process_flag/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_flag-2)).

Yet, this does not solve the problem, as the factory itself could terminate abnormally. It would be restarted by its supervisor and all states would be lost, without proper cleanup. So you need to make sure that what needs to be done on children start is undone when the factory terminates.

Comment: Thanks for many great insights, but it seems, that they are not fully relevant to my case. During the process life it gains a certain (simple) state. It should be then preserved and restored after restart. Sill, trying to restore the state of the process that is brand new causes a deadlock. The reason: all of described processes are created by gen_server, that works as a factory for them. It is also the process that modify their state. So, the call hierarchy is: sth -> factory (create process) -> supervisor (add child) -> child (init) -> factory (modify my state) = deadlock = timeout.

Comment: I updated the response to take the factory example into account. The deadlock can be avoided with async messages. The child could send itself an async message in the init handler (with `gen_server:cast(self(), Message)`) and the corresponding `handle_cast` handler would fetch the state from the factory. Alternatively, if the child is never to be restarted by the supervisor, the factory could provide the state just after starting the child.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by clarify why a process will die, and then what is the relevant strategy to restart properly (You don't give information about this).
Then if it is a normal behavior of your application that those processes terminate (for example session time out), my opinion is that you should try to separate the task that can die from the one that is in charge to store the state.
It may be also relevant to keep information in ets, dets or mnesia.
But as Paul said try to stick to the OTP principles.

Answer (score 0):

Supervised processes are OTP processes.  Your supervisor is therefore starting otp processes like gen_server.  To see when processes are restarted make your own nameserver, and then use gen_server:start_link({via, YourModule, Identifier}... to track restarts.